# Response to "O my son" by Vyasadeva

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavata-purana, vyasa, shuka

When Shuka was leaving Vyasa, Vyasa cried "O my son" to which it is said that trees animals replied Vyasa
Statement given in Srimad Bhagavatham from https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/

> Vyāsadeva, fearing separation from him, cried out, “O my son!” Indeed, only the trees, which were absorbed in the same feelings of separation, echoed in response to the begrieved father.

Here it is said that trees echoed for also they were sad from separation from Shuka,

But The story I have been told in an Upanyasam was that the trees, animals all replied "yes" as they all considered themselves equal to Shuka ( Shuka always saw everyone equally, he also saw God in them )
What was the true emotion behind the reply

I don't know Sanskrit, so the Slokha also its meaning if provided would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> dvaipayano viraha-katara ajuhava
> putreti tan-mayataya taravo bhinedus
> tam sarva-bhuta-hrdayam munim anato smi
> yam pravrajantam anupetam apeta-krtyam

Meaning -

> Śrīla Sūta Gosvāmī said: Let me offer my respectful obeisances unto that great sage (Śukadeva Gosvāmī) who can enter the hearts of all. When he went away to take up the renounced order of life (sannyāsa), leaving home without undergoing reformation by the sacred thread or the ceremonies observed by the higher castes, his father, Vyāsadeva, fearing separation from him, cried out, "O my son!" Indeed, only the trees, which were absorbed in the same feelings of separation, echoed in response to the begrieved father.

So the slokha clearly mentions the grieve by trees and all living beings being separated from Shuka deva